# como puedo eliminar todas las filas de una tabla usando javascript

Tags: javascript

deseo eliminar todas las filas de una tabla usando javascript sin jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es mi tabla y la lleno usando una función, esta funcion se ejecuta con un boton, pero quiero eliminar todas las filas de la tabla, antes de ejecutar la función ya que si esta llena se repite lo mismo.

en fin solo me gustaría saber como eliminar las filas de la tabla sin usar jquery de la forma mas sencilla.

gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: ¿qué función estás utilizando? añádela a tu pregunta, danos toda la información posible.

Comment: pues la función no es importante considero yo, ya que solo me gustaría saber como eliminar todas las filas que contiene una tabla. he encontrado otras respuestas en stackO pero todas usan jquery, y no quiero utilizar jquery.

Comment: Pues sin utilizar ninguna función solo se me ocurre que le des al boton Suprimir o a la tecla retroceso :-)   Bromas aparte, aqui ayudamos cuando se nos plantea un problema con un código, un error o un comportamiento indeseado, pero no hacemos código a medida (o no deberiamos) pues para eso estan los programadores que cobran.  Son las normas del sitio. Léete [ask]  y haz el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio y cómo deben ser las preguntas para ser aceptadas y bien recibidas. En caso contrario es probable que sea cerrada y/o reciba votos negativos, lo siento.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, que fila quieres eliminar?
Si quieres eliminar la fila de thead puedes hacer esto: (en javascript)

```
const thead = document.querySelectorAll('thead');
const filas = document.querySelectorAll('thead > tr');
```

Con esto, tienes al thead (padre de las filas) y las filas en un array. Es mas recomendando usar document.getElementById, pero para eso, al thead le tienes que poner un id cualquiera, y en vez de poner 'thead' pones document.getElementById('thead'); Pero esto funcionaria si solo tienes una SOLA tabla. Despues, como paso final:

```
for(let i=0; i<filas.length; i++){
  thead.removeChild(filas);
}
```

Te recomiendo que investigues sobre elementos HTML en javascript, (removeChild, createElement) etc. Si queres eliminar las filas de la etiqueta tbody, haces lo mismo pero en vez de poner thead, pones tbody. Si queres que se ejecute antes de una función, podes en la misma funcion, poner esto primero y luego que se ejecute el resto, o como vos quieras.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: y como seria si tengo dos tablas?, esta respuesta funciona correctamente pero me gustaría saber la respuesta para dos tablas. gracias

Comment: Sería lo mismo pero en vez de tbody o thead, tendrías que ponerle a cada uno un id e ir incrementando y en vez de poner tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'), pondrias: tbody1 = document.getElementById('tbody1'), e ir incrementando. Y para las filas pondrías lo mismo pero document.querySelectorAll('tbody#(ID DEL TBODY) > tr')